# Simplest "configure" script ever that passes prefix argument to Makefile? (configure hello world)

Tags: makefile, configure, autoconf, automake

My end goal is to produce a simple .deb package.

For that I've read it's better to provide 3 build phases in my build infrastructure of the project, rather than do it in the debian/ folder.

So first thing I need is a configure script, however I want the simplest configure script ever that just receives a "--prefix" argument and passes its value to the Makefile system (so the "install" target of the makefile can copy the files over to it).

Can I do this without using autoconf? I know autoconf is great but for the simplest configuration-phase ever I may not need it yet so badly.

Thanks

Comment: What about other make targets that autotools users expect like: 'make uninstall', 'make dist', 'make distcheck', 'make DESTDIR=/path install'?

Comment: "autotools users"? I only care about what the .deb generation needs (for now)

Comment: because the deb creation tools assume make by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
prefix=NONE
test "$prefix" = NONE && prefix=/usr/local

usage ()
{
    echo ""
    echo "Usage : configure [--prefix=PREFIX]"
    echo ""
}

while test x$1 != x; do
    case $1 in
        --prefix=*)
            prefix=`echo $1 | sed 's/--prefix=//'`
            ;;
        --prefix)
            shift
            prefix=$1
            ;;
        --help)
            usage
            exit
            ;;
        *)
            echo Warning: unknown argument $1 >&2
            usage
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

echo -n "SUBDIRS = " > config.make

echo Configuration Summary
echo ---------------------
echo
echo "MyApp has been configured with "
echo "    prefix = $prefix"
echo
echo >> config.make
echo

echo -n  "prefix=$prefix" >> config.make
```

Then in the Makefile the first thing I need to do is:

```
top_srcdir=.
CONFIG_MAKE=$(top_srcdir)/config.make

-include $(top_srcdir)/config.make
```

I would be interested if there are better solutions than this.

Comment: `test x$1 != x` will fail if `$1` contains any whitespace.

Comment: `test x"$1" != x`, or `test "${1+set}" = set`

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it without autoconf. You're basically saying that you want to mimic one specific behavior of autoconf, without knowing all the ramifications and related behaviors that autoconf adds. This violates the principle of least surprise, as users (or even your deb tool) will expect the related behaviors (`DESTDIR`, `--exec-prefix`, etc.). Just use autoconf. You can make your `configure.ac` really simple:

```
AC_INIT([My App], [1.0], [my-email@me.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall foreign])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

Comment: I agree but you didn't get my point: I want to really feel the pain of not using autoconf to auto-convince me that I need autoconf. This way I can understand better the abstraction it provides.

Comment: Okay... maybe use the snippet I provided to generate a `configure` script and then read all 14 kilobytes of it? ;-)

Comment: Take an existing simple package then and look what autoconf provides there.

Comment: An existing simple package wouldn't be the simplest package ever ;)